Vue3 pass Tween object to parent to use setTween on scrollMagicScene
I want to create a TweenMax in a Vue Component. In the parent I have created a ScrollMagic.Scene and want to use .setTween to sync them.
In my child component I used an event to pass it onMounted to the parent.
const title = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

const emit = defineEmits(['titleAnimation']);


    onMounted(() => {
        const titleTween = TweenMax.fromTo(
            title.value!,
            1, 
            { x: 0, opacity: 1  }, 
            { x: -145, opacity: 0 }
        );

        emit('titleAnimation', titleTween);
    });

In my parent I am using a callback to fetch this event and then set the value to a local variable.
const animation = ref<TweenMax | null>(null);

function callback(n) {
    animation.value = n;
}

<HomePageCard1 @titleAnimation="callback"/>

Inside the parent onMounted I then set the Tween.
let foo = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            duration: 1000,
            triggerElement: intro.value,
            triggerHook: 0 
        })
        .setTween(toRaw(animation.value))
        .addTo(controller)

The first Problem is the animation.value is a Proxy which doesn't seem to work, so I had to use toRaw on it.
At some point also my animated text just disappeared. All of this doesn't really some like a clean solution. Is there any better way to do this.
On another note:
Where do I get the correct Tween types for Typescript?
I wanted to have a simple way like passing props to create something like a binding.
When I tried the above it just worked sometimes.
